# Geoserver GetFeatureInfo Issue

Tags: geoserver, getfeatureinfo

I am using Geoserver version 2.5.2

I am having 2 different layers and both are raster/wms layers.
I have configured GetFeatureInfo for both layers on click event.

```
Layer 1: Line Layer (Single Tile = False, Loading with GWC)
Layer 2: Point Layer (Single Tile = True, Loading without GWC)
```

Issue: When I click on the map where layer 1 and layer 2 both exist, sometimes geoserver is giving error in response for any one of GetFeatureInfo.

> Error: java.io.IOException: Error occured processing content template
>   content.ftl for org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@d8473123 Error occured
>   processing content template content.ftl for
>   org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@d8473123 Expression feature.pointid is
>   undefined on line 6, column 37 in content.ftl.

When i got this error, GetFeatureInfo response for Layer 2 was fine but i got error in GetFeatureInfo response of Layer 1.

If you see the error message, there is a feature attribute exist **Expression feature.pointid is undefined**. but pointid is not a feature of Layer 1. it exists in Layer 2.

All parameters are valid.
GetFeatureInfo for Separate layer click is working fine.

Any one have idea regarding this issue ?

Comment: please edit your question with the actual error message and the code you are using to create the getFeatureInfo request and the url used to make the request

Comment: I have updated the question content. please see updates.